# VLC recording short clips

Tags: bash, video, vlc, raspberry-pi2

I have encountered a problem that should not be so hard but I cant solve it.
I would like to record one hour movie with VLC, but it should be 1 clip/ minute.

60 minuts = 60 clips that is 1 minute long.

I have tried this in bash:

```
vlc_loop="1"
vlc_max_loop="60"

while [ $vlc_loop -le $vlc_max_loop ]
do
cvlc rtsp://xxxx:xxxx@192.168.x.xxx:xxx/xxx/video_audio/profile04 --run-time=60 --sout file/mp4:/home/pi/test/stream_$vlc_loop.mp4 --play-and-exit 
vlc_loop=$(( $vlc_loop + 1 ))
done
```

But it does not work because VLC takes 3 seconds in which to start, so there will be a delay for 3 seconds between each clip.

I have also tried this:

```
vlc_loop="1"
vlc_max_loop="60"

while [ $vlc_loop -le $vlc_max_loop ]
do
cvlc rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.2.201:88/live/video_audio/profile04 --run-time=60 --sout file/mp4:/home/pi/test/stream_$vlc_loop.mp4 --play-and-exit &
sleep 58
vlc_loop=$(( $vlc_loop + 1 ))
done
```

The problem here is that 1/10 off the clips that gets recorded cant be played?

I really hope that there is someone out there who can explain why option 2 is not working. Or give me tips on other options to get this to work?

I apologize in advance for my bad English.

Sincerely Joakim

Comment: What does the `raspberry-pi2` tag has to do with this question?

Comment: Not an answer (hence a comment), but incrementing is much easier written as `(( ++vlc_loop ))`.

Comment: sjsam: I run the script on an RP, no idea if that affects anything? probably not, but I tag it anyway.